# Registering callbacks from text configuration file

Tags: c++, maps

I have a general problem where I have an array of function pointers.  The challenge is to bind the functions to locations in the array based on a text configuration file.  Is there a better way to do this than a gigantic if-else-else-...-else block?

Is it easier to implement functors and bind locations to instances of a type?

EDIT: For example, I might have:

```
void func1();
void func2();

void (*fptr[2])();
```

I want to have an input configuration file that tells me that func1 goes in fptr[0] and func2 goes in fptr[1].

func1, 0
func2, 1

if-else means I stream the line in and I get a string fname = "func1", and a location_in_the_array, 0.  So I'll have a block:

```
if (fname.compare("func1")) 
{
  fptr[location_in_the_array] = func1;
}
else if (...) {}
```

A map is a good idea, and it has flitted in an out of my brain a couple of times, but I am a space cadet, and forgot it before I asked.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Function pointers aren't constant, so even if it was a good idea you couldn't just store the address in the file in an array, which necessitates some sort of encoding. And since C++ doesn't really have reflection, you need to do it with an if/else. But I have this feeling that you'd be better off with a map.

Comment: That depends a lot on the text file's format. Basically, what you need to do is called "parsing". For simple formats, a gigantic `if`/`else if` block might do the job, but for anything else, other techniques are preferred. What does your text file look like?

Comment: You need to elaborate more on what you're trying to do, or provide some example code.  It's hard to make sense out of the phrase "bind the functions to locations in the array based on a text configuration file"

Comment: @sbi I haven't spec'ed the file format yet.  I'm trying to figure out how to do it.  It is exactly parsing, but it is a limited parse, and I want to do it at runtime.

Comment: @David: That's very limited information nonetheless, but I'll try...

Comment: @Robert If you write up "Use a map" as an answer, I'll pick it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming a file format like

> a
>      c
>      a
>      b

this should parse it and put function pointers into a `std::vector` accordingly:

```
// Beware, untested code ahead!

typedef void (*func_t)();
typedef std::map<std::string, func_t>   func_map_t;
typedef func_map_t::value_type          func_map_entry_t;

void f1() {}
void f2() {}
void f3() {}

const func_map_entry_t func_map_entries[] = { func_map_entry_t("a", &f1)
                                            , func_map_entry_t("b", &f2)
                                            , func_map_entry_t("c", &f3) };

const func_map_t func_map( func_map_entries
                         , func_map_entries + sizeof(func_map_entries)
                                            / sizeof(func_map_entries[0]));

func_t read_line(std::istream& is)
{
    std::string token;
    if(!(is >> token)) throw "you need better error handling!";
    func_map_t::const_iterator found = func_map.find(token);
    if(found == func_map.end()) throw "you need better error handling!";
    return found->second;
}

std::vector<func_t> read_config(std::istream& is)
{
    std::vector<func_t> result;
    std::string line;
    while(std::getline(is,line))
    {
        std::istringstream iss(line);
        func_t func = read_line(iss);
        if(!func) throw "you need better error handling!";
        result.push_back(func);
    }
    if(is.eof()) throw "you need better error handling!";
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> If you write up "Use a map" as an answer, I'll pick it.

Use a map.

More specifically, your text file contains the keys to the map, and the map maps keys to function pointers. Come up with a unique name for each function (could be the function name! perhaps plus argument types if you've got overloading), store it in the text file, and run each entry through the map to get the function pointer to store in the array.

Comment: I feel ingenuous about saying I'd pick it then picking sbi's answer [because it is more exhaustive].  If you feel sleighted by it, I'll change to pick your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Would indirection help?

For example, take your function pointers and at compile time assign them to a hash table by name, perhaps the identifier of function's name.

Then at runtime load the text file, which is a list of names.

Create an array by looking up the identifier, find its function pointer in the hash table, and fill the array.